# How to reduce Apps Script execution time to under 45 seconds for GWAO when already using arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization, google-docs, google-workspace-add-ons

I can't figure out how to make this script run in under 45 seconds (the limit for Google Workspace Add-ons). The script takes content from different columns in a Google Docs table and ports it to columns F and H in a spreadsheet. The table and spreadsheet have ~700 rows. Any help is appreciated!

```
function docToSheet(event) {
  try {
    let ssInput = event.formInputs.url[0];
    let sheetName = event.formInputs.sheet_name[0];
    let sourceSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssInput);
    let sourceSheet = sourceSs.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    let range = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
    let length = range.getNumRows();
    let sourceColF = sourceSheet.getRange("F3:F" + length);
    let sourceColH = sourceSheet.getRange("H3:H" + length);


    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();

    let searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
    let element = searchElement.getElement();
    let table = element.asTable();

// Creates array to set values with for Column F
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
      array[i] = [];
      let cellText = table.getCell(i, 3).getText();
      for (let j = 0; j < table.getNumRows(); j++) {
        array[i][0] = cellText;
      }
    }
    
    // Creates array to set values with for Column H

    let array2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
      array2[i] = [];
      let cellText = table.getCell(i, 5).getText();
      for (let j = 0; j < table.getNumRows(); j++) {
        array2[i][0] = cellText;
      }
    }

    sourceColF.setValues(array);
    sourceColH.setValues(array2);

    let card = docsSuccessCard();
    let navigation = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(card);

    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(navigation)
      .build();
  }
  catch {
    let card = docsErrorCard();
    let navigation = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(card);
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(navigation)
      .build();
  }

}
```

Comment: Try replacing `table.getNumRows()` with the actual value in the loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to reduce the execution time of a Google Apps Script function you should try to reduce the calls to Google Apps Script services.

Ideas

1. Instead of using multiple `Sheet.getRange` use [Sheet.getRangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
2. Instead of doing multiple `Range.setValues` try to do a single one
3. Whenever it be possible instead of reading some parameters use hardcoded values.

Or

- Instead of using the Spreadsheet Service use the Advanced Sheets Service
- Instead of using the Document Service use the Advanced Documents Service
- When writing to a spreadsheet / document use the corresponding batchUpdate method.

Consider to try a different approach

1. Instead of doing many things on a single function, split them into two or more functions.
2. Use your function to create one time trigger
3. Use a jobs queue and process them using a trigger
4. Instead of using a Workspace add-on, use an Editor add-on as it allows use client-side code for your add-on UI as it has execution time limit of 6 / 30 mins depending on the account type.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked much faster once I set values on a single range instead of multiple ranges (your second idea).